# Office Online server disable Open in Reading View button

Tags: ms-word, ms-wopi, office-online-server

Office Online Server installation is hosted on our server. We have implementation of WOPI protocol which is working fine.

Problem is when a document is locked, in a error screen, additional button "Open in Reading View" is shown. How to remove that button from the error screen.

[image]

Comment: StackOverflow concentrates on programming-related topics. Your question falls under networking/server. There's a Server Fault section on Stack Exchange which would be the better place to ask this?

Comment: @CindyMeister It is a perfectly valid programmer question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to influence that behavior - neither in the [WOPI Host capabilities](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#wopi-host-capabilities-properties) nor in the [PostMessage](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scenarios/postmessage.html#using-postmessage-to-interact-with-the-wac-application-iframe) events.

Comment: I have a demo instance of OOS which does not suffer from this problem. Version of OOS are the same. I suspect in a configuration.